# calling async code in useState throwing null of undefined error

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am pretty new to react and redux. I am trying to call get method API in useEffect hook but the function I am calling isn't getting invoked at all. the same function is invoked when I tried calling outside the useEffect and the state is also updated but I still got that error `Cannot read property 'map' of null`. so in both the cases, the common thing is getting the error and my code seems good to me. all other functions and states are working except this and I am not able to figure out what I am missing. any help very much is appreciated. thank you.

Orders.js

```
const orders = (props) => {
    // getting the orders
    useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchOrders();
    }, []);

    let orders;
    if(props.loading || props.error) {
        orders = <Loading />
    }
    console.log(props)
    orders = props.orders.map((order) => <Order 
            key={order.id}
            ingredients={order.ingredients} 
            price={order.price}
            customer={order.customerDetails}
    />); 
    return(
    <div>
        {orders}
    </div>
    )
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        orders: state.orders,
        error: state.error,
        loading: state.loading
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchOrders: () => dispatch(getOrders())
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (errorHandler(orders, axiosInstance));
```

action.js

```
  // not invoking
const getOrders = () => {
    return dispatch => {
       axiosInstance.get('/orders.json').then(res => {
            const ordersData = transformData(res);
            dispatch(fetchOrders(ordersData));
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
}

const transformData = (response) => {

    // simplified logic
    const ordersData = [];
    if(response.data) {
        for (let key in response.data) {
            ordersData.unshift({
                ...response.data[key],
                id: key
            })
        }
    }
    return ordersData;
}

const fetchOrders = (ordersData) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.GET_ORDERS,
        orders: ordersData
    }
}

export { getOrders }
```

reducer.js

```
const reducer = (state = intialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
              .
              .
        case actionType.GET_ORDERS:
            return setOrders(state, action);
              .
              .
        default:
        return state;
    }
}

const setOrders = (state, action) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        orders: action.orders.concat(),
        error: false,
        loading: false
    }
}
```